# Configuring WSDL Based Proxy in WSO2 version 4.6

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have down loaded WSO2 ESB Version 4.6 and started the server.  Clicked on proxy service. There I have selected WSDL Proxy option. It is asking the following for creating proxy.

Proxy Service Name* OpportunityService

WSDL URI* https://crm-aufsn4x0ruf.oracleoutsourcing.com//opptyMgmtOpportunities/OpportunityService?WSDL

WSDL Service* https://crm-aufsn4x0ruf.oracleoutsourcing.com:443/opptyMgmtOpportunities/OpportunityService

WSDL Port* 443

I just want consume this external web service via ESB. So I dont want publish. Did not configure any publish related fields. Now When I click on create it throws exception "Failed to add proxy service: OpportunityService. Check whether the Proxy already exists
". But I am sure that there is no existed service with that. I have tried with different names but the error is same.

I suspect that may gave values wrong for fields WSDL Service and WSDL Port. If click on Test URI its giving success.Can any one please suggest where I am doing wrong.

Thanks&Regards,
Raghu

Answer (score 3):

For wsdl service parameter you need to give the `<wsdl:service name>`which you can find in the particular wsdl itself. I dont think it will be a URI like you have mentioned above. Likewise for port you can find the  `<wsdl:port>` parameter in the wsdl.

Comment: To more more explicit, in your example of the WSDL at `https://crm-aufsn4x0ruf.oracleoutsourcing.com/opptyMgmtOpportunities/OpportunityService?WSDL`, the `WSDL Service` would be `OpportunityService` and the corresponding `WSDL Port` would be `OpportunityServiceSoapHttpPort`. These can be found very near the bottom of the WSDL. The word `port` is a bit overloaded but does have specific meaning in the world of SOAP services.